# How select an element by class name, previously loaded in DOM

Tags: jquery

I write a simple piece of code that creates a div and assign it a class name:

```
$('#create_div').click( 
function() {    
  div = $("<div>").addClass("myClass");
  $("body").append(div); 
} 
);
```

Ok: after "create_div" button is fired the function appends the new div to body container.

Now... : **How to select the new element created ? How do I reach it?**
I have tried:

```
$('.myClass').click( 
function() {    
  // do something 
} 
);
```

but it doesn't works.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where do you run the second snippet? Are you sure it's ran after the element has been added to the page?

Comment: I solved Thanks to Matti & AutomatedTester. Now it's all ok!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.myClass').live('click', 
function() {    
  // do something 
} 
);
```

Should bind to an element that is created after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: that's equivalent to using `.click()`. it's just a shorthand.

Comment: That does exactly the same thing as his code. Did you mean `live()`?

Comment: I solved. Thanks to Matti & AutomatedTester. Now it's all ok!

Answer (score 0):

This would also work:

```
  div = $("div").addClass("myClass"); //NOTE: not <div> !!
  $("body").append(div); 

  div.click(function(e) {
    //Do Something
  });
```